# Entering coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am trying to import coordinates in QGIS but they only appear as single line in the delimited text file.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hello Katja, welcome to GIS.SE. Some more information would be helpful, e.g. what have you tried so far? Did you tried changing the custom delimiters or saving your data as a CSV?

Comment: Do you actually have only one line in your text file? Or does it appear this way in QGIS only?

Comment: Do you know how the text file is delimited? Try changing the file extension of the text file to .csv and open it in Excel, does it display across multiple columns or is in just one cell?

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that your file is formatted with a single line terminator, but QGis is expecting a double line terminator.  Your screen shot seems to show that your using an Apple Mac, which understands single charachter line terminators, so in theory this actually shouldn't be a problem, however as I mention below, QGis doesn't always get this right.

This has been a problem for years with any kind of plain ascii text, and there are tools to deal with it, far too many to list here, but a quick serch for "Carriage Return Conversion" will find you a ton of them, including some on-line ones in the browser.

Basically, most Linux and Mac systems only use an ascii code of 10 to signal the end of the line, where as windows systems use an ascii code of 13, followed by an ascii code of 10 *(or is it 10/13 I can never remember :-) )*

Point is, your lines, for windows to see them as seperate individual lines need to be formatted like this

```
data data data(13)(10)
data data data(13)(10)
data data data(13)(10)
```

Right now it would appear that your file is actually formatted like this

```
data data data(10)
data data data(10)
data data data(10)
```

Some applications on windows can tell the difference, some cannot, and over the years unfortunately, I've regularly found QGis often falls into the later category.

What I do personally, is I try to load the file into "Ultra Edit" which is a paid for text editor that I use, beacuse if the file does not have the correct line termination, then it will ask me if I want to correct it, and on clicking yes it will do so.

I can't tell you to use ultra edit unless you already have it, given that it's a paid for product, but as far as I know, many of the more popular text editors, such as notepad++ and VS-Code either can do it or have a plug in for it.

The other thing I also notice looking at your screen shot, is the delimiter between the fields.

It looks like a space, but if you do have Mac/Linux line terminators, then that's very likley to be a TAB, so watch out for that one too, I've had to spend hours correcting data before beacuse I got tabs and spaces mixed up.

Bottom line, run your file through some kind of line terminator or Carriage Return convertor, and you'll likley find it'll solve your problem.

and don't worry... this problem existed back in the 1970's too, it's not a new thing :-)